# Getting databases from failover group Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I was wondering if anybody can provide some insight into getting a list of databases from a `FailoverGroup`. I am half way there but when iterating over the databases within a `FailoverGroup`, the databases are a bunch of strings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.failovergroup.databases?view=azure-dotnet). I want to convert this into a database object but because this is represented as a fully qualified name this is proving to be a little difficult to do unless I start splitting the string and indexing parts of it.

For example, the database name is returned as `/subscriptions/[subscription_id]/resourceGroups/[resource_group]/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/[sql_server]/databases/MyDatabaseName`

When I use the cmdlet `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase` passing the above string, it doesn't place nice saying it doesn't exist. I can get this to work if I were to split the string and extract the database name only but that seems a little overkill.

In a nutshell, is there a way to cast the value returned in `FailoverGroup.Databases` to an instance of `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseModel`

I am using the following to get fail over groups if this helps.. `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName`

Comment: Do you want to get database within a failovergroup by using Azure CLI 2.0 or 1.0?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT using version 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Based on my knowledge, currently, Azure CLI 2.0 does not support get failover group information. You could check [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest).

You could use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/failovergroups/get) to get it.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/failoverGroups/{failoverGroupName}?api-version=2015-05-01-preview
```

Comment: @Dr Schizo In your scenario, rest api maybe is a good solution. If you want  more future help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell:

`Get-AzureRmResource -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -ResourceId /subscriptions/[subscription_id]/resourceGroups/[resource_group]/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/[sql_server]/databases/MyDatabaseName`

Using Azure CLI:

`az resource show --api-version 2014-04-01 --ids /subscriptions/[subscription_id]/resourceGroups/[resource_group]/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/[sql_server]/databases/MyDatabaseName`